# Calling Microsoft Graph API using first party app fails with insufficient privileges to complete the operation on "SubscribedSkus API"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Calling microsoft graph API https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus fails with
"code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
This is happening if we create a new user in the tenant who is non admin. But while calling this with Admin user it works just fine. Even it works for any microsoft user in the tenant.

This is the below code I used to try.

```
public static async Task TestAadGraph()
    {
        // using obo token of the user.
        var graphToken = await GetTokenAsync(UserId, Token, "https://graph.microsoft.com");

        var aadGraphClient = new AadGraphClient(new HttpClient());

        var licenseResponse = await aadGraphClient.GetTenantLicenseDetailAsync(graphToken);
        foreach (var license in licenseResponse)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sku ID: {0}", license.SkuId);
            Console.WriteLine("Sku Part Number: {0}", license.SkuPartNumber);

            foreach (var plan in license.ServicePlans)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Plan Id: {0}", plan.ServicePlanId);
                Console.WriteLine("Plan Name: {0}", plan.ServicePlanName);
            }
        }
    }

 public async Task<SubscribedSku[]> GetTenantLicenseDetailAsync(string accessToken)
    {
        var request = new RequestMessage
        {
            BearerToken = accessToken,
            Endpoint = new Uri("http://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus"),
        };

        var response = await _httpClient.FetchAsync<SubscribedSkusResponse>(request);

        return response.Value;
    }

   public static async Task<T> FetchAsync<T>(this HttpClient httpClient, RequestMessage request, Action<HttpResponseMessage, string> responseCallback) where T : class
    {
        request.Method = request.Method ?? HttpMethod.Get;
        request.MediaType = request.MediaType ?? "application/json";

        using (HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(request.Method, 
            UrlHelper.AppendParameters(request.Params, request.Endpoint)))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.BearerToken))
            {
                message.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", 
                request.BearerToken);
            }

            if (request.Headers != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> header in request.Headers)
                {
                    message.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Content))
            {
                message.Content = new StringContent(request.Content, Encoding.UTF8, 
                request.MediaType);
            }`

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(message))
            {
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (responseCallback != null)
                {
                    responseCallback?.Invoke(response, json);
                }

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    if (predictor != null)
                    {
                        json = predictor(JToken.Parse(json)).ToString();
                    }

                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new WebRequestException(response, json);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But if start using https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/subscribedSkus this works totally fine with out exceptions on the same app.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try the same call for the new created user in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to see if the same scene exists. If not, it means the there is nothing wrong with the new user.

Then debug your code and copy the graphToken into https://jwt.io/ and see if the Decoded result has one of the required Delegated permissions：`Organization.Read.All, Directory.Read.All, Organization.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All`. Note that the "upn" should be the username of the new created user.

[image]

If the required permissions do not exist, you will need to assign permissions in the Azure AD app. See [API permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/notifications-integration-app-registration#api-permissions).

Answer (score 0):

Perfect. Adding permission to the first party app has actually worked.